# jQuery When button is clicked check to make sure given criteria is fulfilled then redirect page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple HTML form with a button with the class 'next-btn'. The form uses a simple validator, and when the submit button is clicked and the input fields are not validated, the '.form-group' container of the input field gets a class of '.has-error'.

What I want to achieve is, when '.next-btn' button is clicked check to make sure no "#step-1 .form-group" has any '.has-error' class then proceed to redirecting the page to the a given url "page2.html".

How can this be done using jQuery? I believe we can start with :

```
$('.next-btn').on('click', function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    // if #step1 .form-group does not have class of .has-error
   // Redirect to page2.html [window.location.href = "http://page2.com";?]
});
```

Much appreciated!

**Edit:** 
Here is the HTML:

```
 <form role="form" class="order-form" method="get">
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
        <div class="steps-inner">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="vehicle_year" class="form-control" placeholder="Car Year" data-error="Car Year is required" required />
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div><!-- end form-group -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                             <input type="text" name="vehicle_make" class="form-control" data-error="Make is required" placeholder="Make" required />
                             <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div><!-- end form-group -->
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end row -->

                 <div class="text-center form-submit">
                     <button class="btn next-btn next-btn1" type="submit">Next <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></button>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end steps-inner -->
    </div><!-- end setup-content -->
</form><!-- end order-form -->
```

Comment: Please can you post what the html looks like with and without the has-error class.

Comment: added the HTML, please check

Comment: But surely it is the button submit which triggers the form validation in the first place?

Comment: Yes. I am using the bootstrap validator http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

And in case you are interested, the live link of my code is: http://www.revolutionarycoder.com/qweex-test/step1.html

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution:

```
$('.next-btn').on('click', function() {
    var haveErrors = false;
    $formGroups = $('#step-1 .form-group');
    $formGroups.each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('has-error')) {
        haveErrors = true;
      }
    });

  if (haveErrors) {
    console.log('error');
  } else {
    console.log('no error');
  }
});
```

Comment: this redirects the page to page2.com even if .form-group has a class of 'has-error'. (ofcourse I modified your code from "form.order-form" to "#step-1 .form-group" as that is what I required.

Comment: @AlexZahir I have updated answer. Now it should work.